# How to add an object to a NSMutableArray that is stored in a CoreData iOS database?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass where `absences` is an `NSMutableArray`

```
@interface Record : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) id absences;
@end
```

I want to be able to add items to the absences array; however, if I do `[myRecord.absences addObject:SomeObj` the record does not save properly.  It almost appears that the `NSManagedObject` does not know that I updated the `absences` array.

Nevertheless, if I add `SomeObj` to some `localAray`, then set `myRecord.absences = localArray`, the `NSManagedObject` saves correctly.

Can someone explain this behaviour and how I might avoid it...thanks

Comment: Duplicate? Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104075/saving-an-nsmutablearray-to-core-data

Comment: There's a pretty big difference between Core Data and SQLite (function-wise).  Which one are you using?

Comment: I'me using Core Data...but doesn't this use SQLite underneath? Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right, in the first case you're changing an object outside of NSManagedObject field of view. To solve this, [Apple doc says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html) the following

> For mutable values, you should either transfer ownership of the value to Core Data, or implement custom accessor methods to always perform a copy.

So declaring your property with `(copy)` should suffice.

Comment: So in `Record` I would do: `@property (nonatomic, retain, copy) id absences;`?  Am I understanding correctly that adding the word `copy` means that whenever you try to set this property it will copy the value rather than just setting it directly?

Comment: You replace `retain` with `copy`, and yes your value will always be copied.